# 1064 mySQL error: AS salary ON resume.jobsalaryrange = salary.id ' at line 6

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I get this error:

> `1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;  AS salary ON resume.jobsalaryrange = salary.id ' at line 6 SQL=SELECT resume.*, cat.cat_title, jobtype.title AS jobtypetitle , salary.rangestart, salary.rangeend , currency.symbol FROM`_js_job_resume`AS resume JOIN`_js_job_jobtypes`AS jobtype ON resume.jobtype = jobtype.id LEFT JOIN`_js_job_currencies`AS currency ON currency.id = resume.currencyid AND currency.id = LEFT JOIN`_js_job_salaryrange`AS salary ON resume.jobsalaryrange = salary.id ,`_js_job_categories`AS cat WHERE resume.job_category = cat.id AND resume.status = 1 AND resume.searchable = 1 AND resume.nationality = 'KE' AND resume.iamavailable = 20 AND resume.jobtype = 2`

From this query:

```
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $total = $db->loadResult();

    if ( $total <= $limitstart ) $limitstart = 0;
    $query = "SELECT resume.*, cat.cat_title, jobtype.title AS jobtypetitle
            , salary.rangestart, salary.rangeend , currency.symbol
            FROM `#__js_job_resume` AS resume
            JOIN `#__js_job_jobtypes` AS jobtype ON resume.jobtype = jobtype.id
            LEFT JOIN `#__js_job_currencies` AS currency ON currency.id = resume.currencyid     AND currency.id =  " .$currency."       
            LEFT JOIN `#__js_job_salaryrange` AS salary ON resume.jobsalaryrange = salary.id
            , `#__js_job_categories` AS cat ";
        $query .= "WHERE resume.job_category = cat.id AND resume.status = 1 AND resume.searchable = 1";
    $query .= $wherequery;
```

Anybody any clue? 
It's a tough one for me!

Comment: This doesn't make sense : , `#__js_job_categories` AS cat ";

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It says

```
AND currency.id = LEFT JOIN_js_job_salaryrange AS
```

So it seems that the variable $currency is not set.

If you add just before the query:`$currency = 1;` just to test the query, it might work. You just have to find out what the currency id should be.

Comment: Both of the solutions worked. Indeed, $currency was not set. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your `$currency` variable isn't defined, or evaluates to an empty string. From the error message:

```
... resume.currencyid AND currency.id = LEFT JOIN_js_job_salaryrangeAS salary ...
                                       ^---$currency should be here
```

Comment: Both of the solutions worked. Indeed, $currency was not set. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT resume.*, cat.cat_title, jobtype.title AS jobtypetitle , 
    salary.rangestart, salary.rangeend , currency.symbol 
    FROM _js_job_categories AS cat, _js_job_resume AS resume JOIN _js_job_jobtypes AS jobtype 
    ON resume.jobtype = jobtype.id LEFT JOIN _js_job_currencies AS currency 
    ON currency.id = resume.currencyid AND currency.id = LEFT JOIN _js_job_salaryrange AS salary 
    ON resume.jobsalaryrange = salary.id  
    WHERE resume.job_category = cat.id 
    AND resume.status = 1 AND resume.searchable = 1 
    AND resume.nationality = 'KE' AND resume.iamavailable = 20 
    AND resume.jobtype = 2
```